# Read some byte from begining of stream without changing Position in c#

Tags: c#, sockets

I Have a NetworkStream should handle both ssl and unencrypted

my data is ascii so when i check some first byte of stream i can determine stream is ssl or not

when i detect stream is ssl I cant create sslStream because AuthenticateAsServer should begin from begining of stream
what can I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to allow a Server to accept both SSL and plain text (insecure) connections?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15227492/how-to-allow-a-server-to-accept-both-ssl-and-plain-text-insecure-connections)

Comment: it doesnt help me becasue the class provided by answer is not suitable with sslstream class

Comment: Maybe Stream.Peek can help you? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.peek(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I don't think you understand the code there.  It defines a class that can pass a stream to an SSLStream, but only does so if the underlying data is encrypted. It's literally the same exact question.

Comment: ssl stream dont accept that kind of stream u can test it

Comment: it throw The stream has to be read/write.Parameter name: innerStream exception

Comment: Huh.  Ok.  I just assumed that it would work given that the question is the same and the answer was accepted.  I'll take your word for it though, I must have missed something.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to put back the one byte you needed to peek at. None of the standard streams supports that.

Write a wrapping stream that allows you to prepend a single byte to the stream that you have wrapped. That way, the SSL implementation will not notice any difference.